# Issues properly defining a function that returns strings that start with uppercase letters

Tags: python, list, function, if-statement

I define the function to accept a list of strings as its argument, so that I can then call the function and give it lists of strings which start with both upper and lowercase letters. I want to use the .isupper method with conditional statement(s) to return only strings that have uppercase letters from the string list arguments.

```
def find_upper(strlist):
    for i in strlist:
        if "i".isupper() == True:
            print(i)
            break
        else "i".islower() == True:
            continue

find_upper(['Marco', 'Billy', 'Petey Pelican', 'Chip Block', 'Ash'])
```

But when I pass the function an argument, it returns:

```
 File "<input>", line 8
    else "i".islower() == True:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: ```elif "i".islower() == True```. In any programming language, ```else``` wouldn't have a condition

Comment: In addition to changing `else` to `elif`, you need to remove the quotes from `"i"` as well.  Otherwise it's a string constant rather than the variable `i`.  And it makes no sense to compare the result of a predicate to `True`.  It's *already* a truth value.  Just use `if i.isupper():` and `elif i.islower():` (although the entire `islower()` branch is pointless since it does the same thing as when `i` is mixed case, so just delete it entirely. i.e. all you need is the `isupper()` branch).

Comment: @Sujay and Tom: Thanks for your helpful insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors. Also you have to iterate over string letters, not over list elements. The way you were doing your would get just the string that have only uppercase letters. Check this code:

```py
def find_upper(strlist):
    for string in strlist:
        for s in string:   
            if s.isupper():
                print(string)


find_upper(['Marco', 'Billy', 'Petey Pelican', 'Chip Block', 'ash'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Marco
Billy
Petey Pelican
Petey Pelican
Chip Block
Chip Block
```

You see that it didn´t output the string 'ash', because it doesn´t have a uppercase letter.

Comment: This makes sense, and that's exactly what I didn't understand and needed help seeing. Thank you for helping me in my learning!

Comment: Does it really make sense to print the same string multiple times if it contains more than one uppercase letter?  Also, it's not entirely clear from the question, but if all that's desired is to check if a string *starts* with an uppercase letter, then it might make sense to replace the inner loop with a simple check of the first letter only, i.e. `string[0]`.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn´t make sense. Maybe you can fix this by rmoving the space inside the string before passing the `isupper()` funtion

Answer (score 1):

1. You need not mention `== True`, python understands if an expression evaluates to True or not.
2. Don't use quotation `"i"` python interprets this a string literal, not a variable.
3. Be sure what `.isupper()` does. It returns `True` if all the characters in your string are upper case. e.g. `'Hello'.isupper()` will return `False`. `'HELLO'.isupper()` will return `True`.
4. You should not write a condition after `else` statement.
5. If you don't have any statement to skip, there is no point in using `continue`. In your code, there is no statement after `continue`.
6. There is no use of `break` in your code. As the interpreter reads `break`, it won't execute the loop further. You may be left with many item in the list which haven't been traversed or iterated.

Try this code:

```
def find_upper(strlist):
    for i in strlist:
        if i.isupper():
            print(i)


find_upper(['MACRO', 'Billy', 'Petey Pelican', 'Chip Block', 'ASH'])
```

Output:

```
MACRO
ASH
```

You got MACRO and ASH because these were the only strings in which all their characters are upper case. If you are ever confused about any function, search it online. Be clear about syntax and functions, you can make any code with any logic, Happy learning! You may also use `.istitle()`, it may be more useful in your case. Look it up, if you don't know!

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications. I am making some flash cards to drill these considerations. You have been very helpful in my learning. Thank you again.